# UI Path - Remote Copy paste issue

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, uipath

I am accessing my application which is on 3rd system.So to access this system I am accessing remote from my local system then again remotely accessing the 3rd system.My UI path flow chart works fine.But I am unable to copy paste the text field from my application to my local system.

Comment: You can try saving the required string or data in a variable then use this variable to type on to the remote window or text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to use the "Get OCR text" because you can't scrape data from machines that you access remotely, based on selectors.
Try working with the CITRIX component if you are working in such environments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try enabling local resources in your remote desktop connection settings.

This screengrab shows how to configure it.:
[image: This screengrab shows how to configure it.]